# If $n$ is odd and $abc=(n-a)(n-b)(n-c),$ then $LCM((n,a),(n,b),(n,c))=n.$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $a,b,c,n\in \mathbb Z^{+},2\not\mid n$ and $$abc=(n-a)(n-b)(n-c),$$
>   $x=(n,a),y=(n,b),z=(n,c),$ then $LCM(x,y,z)=n.$

If $n=35,a,b,c=5, 21, 28,$ then $x=(35,5)=5,y=(35,21)=7,z=(35,28)=7,LCM(x,y,z)=35.$

If $n=945,a,b,c=9, 756, 910,$ then $x,y,z=9, 35, 189,LCM(x,y,z)=945.$

I checked all $n<1000$ and this is always true.

(On the other hand, if $2\mid n$ then $LCM(x,y,z)=n$ or $\dfrac n2.$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, consider if $ \gcd(a,b,c) \neq 1$. If so, let $p$ be any prime that divides it, and so $p^3 \mid abc = (n-a)(n-b)(n-c)$. Hence, WLOG $p \mid n-a$, which gives us $p\mid n$. Now, we may divide every term by $p$, and still be in the same situation. Henceforth, assume that $\gcd (a,b,c) = 1$.

Let $p$ be an (odd) prime that divides $n$. Let $p^k$ be the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$. Let $p^\alpha, p^\beta, p^\gamma$ be the largest power of $p$ that divides $a, b, c$ respectively. We have $ p^{\min (k, \alpha ) } $ is the largest power of $p$ that divides $x=(n,a)$. Thus, it remains to show that

$$\max[ \min(k, \alpha), \min (k, \beta), \min (k, \gamma) ] = k, $$

which is equivalent to  $$\max( \alpha, \beta, \gamma ) \geq k.$$

Having motivated looking at this animal, we now show that is it true. WLOG, $ \alpha \geq \beta \geq \gamma = 0$ (since $\gcd(a,b,c) = 1$). If $\beta \geq k$, then we are done. Otherwise, assume that $ k > \beta$.

We will work modulo $p^{k+\beta}$. We are given that

$$ abc = n^3 - (a+b+c)n^2 + (ab+bc+ca) n  -abc $$

Since $k > \beta$ hence $ n^3, n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p^{k+ \beta} }$. As such, we get

$$ abc \equiv (ab+bc+ca)n - abc \equiv -abc \pmod{p^{k+\beta}} $$

Hence, $ \alpha + \beta \geq k + \beta$, which gives us $\alpha \geq k$.

---

Note: The reason for $k > \beta$, is because if $ \alpha \geq \beta > k$, then the $cn^2$ term doesn't disappear when taking mod $p^{k + \beta}$.

Comment: This is very nice, but I think you want to remove the "$k >$" right after "WLOG,". (Unless you wanted to give a proof by contradiction and forgot to add a "suppose", but I think it's nicer to prove directly.)

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I initially did proceed by contradiction, but then I cleaned up the presentation greatly to do it in just this 1 main step.

Comment: @user43208 Filling in the details, I do need a slight argument, and can't simply work directly. I've added the explanation of where things screw up. It's slightly quirky in this scenario, and it would be nice if it can go away.